# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num' in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
List<dynamic> blueButtons = [0.0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.33, 0.34, 0.67, 0.4, 0.2];
List<dynamic> match = [];
 for(int i = 0; i< blueButtons.length; i++) {
    match.add(BID_DATA.indexOf(blueButtons[i]));
  }

 print("Match -> $match");
```

i am trying to add the index of those number and i am getting this error  Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num' i have also tried this one also

```
match.add(BID_DATA.indexOf(blueButtons[i]).toString());
```

Comment: `indexOf` takes a string (not a number). `match.add(BID_DATA.indexOf(blueButtons[i].toString()));` runs, but what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to achive the index of the blueButtons elements in BID_DATA

Comment: match.add(BID_DATA.indexOf(blueButtons[i].toString())); this is showing the wrong syntax

Comment: What type is biddata?

Comment: BID_DATA is double type

Comment: Double doesn't have an indexof method. Do you mean `List<double>`? Please post more code so we can try to understand your question.

Comment: Yes             List<double>